# How does _mm256_shuffle_ps work?

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

I understand how `_mm_shuffle_ps` work. For example, in the following.

```
__m128 r = _mm_shuffle_ps(x,y, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,0,2,0));
```

`r` will have contents, `x[0]`, `x[2]`, `y[0]`, `y[2]`.

But I see that `_MM_SHUFFLE` also takes 4 parameters for `_mm256_shuffle_ps`, while there the vectors would have 8 elements each. So, logically `_MM_SHUFFLE` should have taken 8 parameters. Can someone please explain how this works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_mm256_shuffle_ps` shuffles each of the two 128-bits lanes independently, as if `_mm_shuffle_ps` is called upon two XMM. If you want to shuffle all 8 32-bits elements, you need `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps`

Answer (score 3):

**SSE/AVX instructions that take an immediate operand always only take an 8-bit immediate.**

As usual, [the manual explains how the 8-bit immediate is used](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SHUFPS.html).  It applies the same shuffle to both 128b lanes.

Some instructions have spare bits in immediate in the 128b version, and can use them for the 256b version.  e.g. [256b `shufpd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SHUFPD.html) uses bits 2 and 3 of the immediate for the upper lane, separate from the usual bits 0 and 1 for the lower 128.

`shufps` needs four groups of 2 bits to select one of four elements for each destination element, so there's no extra room in the imm8.